# Change path of rosrun. Couldn't find executables?

Tags: ros, beginner-tutorials, rosrun, catkin-ws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following tutorials of ROS at the ROS wiki

```
//www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/ExaminingPublisherSubscriber.
```

When I try to run `rosrun beginner_tutorials talker`. It tells me that:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named talker below /home/maverick/catkin_ws/install/share/beginner_tutorials
```

I know that the executable is not in the install folder but rather in devel. How can I make it search for rosrun beginner_tutorial talker in

```
devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/talker
```

Additional information: When I ran find -executable -type f the output is given as below:

```
*./devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/add_two_ints_client
./devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/talker
./devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/add_two_ints_server
./devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/listener
./devel/_setup_util.py
./devel/env.sh
./install/_setup_util.py
./install/env.sh
./build/CMakeFiles/CompilerIdC/a.out
./build/CMakeFiles/CompilerIdCXX/a.out
./build/CMakeFiles/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin
./build/CMakeFiles/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_CXX.bin
./build/catkin_generated/installspace/_setup_util.py
./build/catkin_generated/installspace/env.sh
./build/catkin_generated/setup_cached.sh
./build/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh*
```

After using the `env | grep ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` I get:

```
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
```

and I have sourced the file using the following command:

```
source ./devel/setup.bash
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64763/change-path-of-rosrun.-couldn%27t-find-executables?/) by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 729 on 2013-06-11

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-06-11**:
Please post more info, i.e. output of `$ env | grep ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`. Also check whether you did source appropriate `setup.bash` file or not.

**Comment by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) on 2013-06-11**:
I have edited my question up there and have posted my output to $ env| grep ROS_PACKAGE_PATH . Also I have sourced the file using the command source ./devel/setup.bash

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-06-11**:
Something doesn't match. Did you source the setup.bash after the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH display? Did you run catkin_make?

**Comment by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) on 2013-06-11**:
Yes I did all of this. Even after this I am still getting the same errors. When I do roscd beginner_tutorials I get /catkin_ws/install/share/beginner_tutorials$. Why is roscd checking always in the install folder. It should check in the devel because my executables are there. How can I change this.

**Comment by [kiyamelak](https://answers.ros.org/users/27336/kiyamelak/) on 2016-06-29**:
I had the same error and this is same of the things I did. 1.Delete the build and devel folder with our your working directory. 2.Make sure that all that you have followed the overall order and structure with in you CMakeList http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt 3.Include all the package needed

**Comment by [M.Halwani](https://answers.ros.org/users/55796/m.halwani/) on 2020-08-07**:
I'm still having a problem saying

```
 [rosrun] Couldn't find executable named run_emvs below /home/ubuntu/emvs_ws/src/rpg_emvs/mapper_emvs
```

I followed the installation guide in here !
https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_emvs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is wrong - it should also include the path to overlay, i.e. to your catkin workspace.

If `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` didn't change after `$ source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` then there is something wrong with your overlay. Try to [recreate it](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace).

**UPDATE**:

This [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace) may also help. In case you are using *install space* you have to source `setup.bash` from it.

At any rate it will be better to recreate workspace and try again with `$ source devel/setup.sh`

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) on 2013-06-11**:
Thanks. I will try to recreate it

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-11-14**:
Asfandyar, did you resolve the problem. I have been following the same steps but I am unable to do that.

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-11-14**:
To me it seems that this method does not work.

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-02-19**:
This isn't the solution. I have both of `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash`
`source ~/ros_ws/devel/setup.bash` these and I still run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i had a problem like this but when made srv and msg folder with `mkdir`  $

```
 cd ~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials
$ mkdir msg
```

and

```
$ roscd beginner_tutorials
$ mkdir srv
```

look at this [link](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv)
and then run catkin_make and did every thing for talker.cpp and listener.cpp and did source ./devel/setup.bash in my catkin workspace and run `catkin_make` again and we could see :

```
Linking CXX executable /home/fatima/catkin_ws2/devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/talker
Linking CXX executable /home/fatima/catkin_ws2/devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/listener
```

and then :
two executable file were made  in catkin_ws/devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/talker and listener and now it could be run :

```
rosrun beginner_tutorials talker
```

---

Originally posted by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) with karma: 62 on 2015-12-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you should grant execute permission to the file

```
chmod +x exec_file
```

---

Originally posted by [tsadik](https://answers.ros.org/users/29582/tsadik/) with karma: 91 on 2017-03-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Btdr](https://answers.ros.org/users/37008/btdr/) on 2018-08-16**:
Specifically created an account to upvote. Thank you!

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-02-19**:
Where is this file?

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2019-08-16**:
replace exec_file with your file name

**Comment by [Nooyi](https://answers.ros.org/users/44146/nooyi/) on 2020-05-04**:
this worked! thank you so much!!